# Move SQL Server 2008 R2 database files to a new folder location

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Currently i have a list of databases i wish to move on the current server.

DATA:

Current Path: Drive:\MSSQL\DATA\FOLDER

New Path: Drive:\MSSQL\DATA

LOGS:

Current Path: Drive:\MYSSQL\LOGS\FOLDER

New Path: Drive:\MYSSQL\LOGS

Is there a SQL script that can be used to set offline multiple databases, detactch them and attach them to the new location? This is also a production enviroment and are pretty large databases (a backup and restore would take much longer). In total 9 databases need to be moved, is this a simple procedure aslong as the location and user have required permissions? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple procedure, and you don't really need to detach the database to do it either, you can just do something along the lines of:

- set db offline
- alter the file location in the master db (using alter database)
- physically move the files
- set db online

The process is described in the following article:

[Move User Databases](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345483.aspx)

So long as the user moving the files has the permissions and the service account you're running SQL server as has full control of the new folder it's quite easy, and something I've done many times.

Doing it for multiple databases too is simple once you've worked out the procedure for doing the first one.

Comment: The reason i am moving some databases is because this particular server is very messy! the master server is currently pointing to the correct location however i have databases restored to another location which i wish to move to the correct location! from what your saying above can i simply use for exmaple:

Alter database databasename set offline
Alter database databasename modify file .....
Alter database databasename set online

Comment: Yeah, there's no need to detach at all, once the database is offline, you can move it's files around, and so long as you use the alter database statement to tell SQL server where you put them, they will just come back online.

Comment: Last question... because this is a production eniroment you didnt mention using SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE ? - this is the first time i have moved databases on SQL and i would like this to go right! when i bring the databases back online i can then ALTER DATABASE databasename SET MULTI_USER is this normal practice ?

Comment: There's no need to put the database into single user mode as you're taking it offline, you can use rollback immediate when setting the DB offline as mentioned in the other answer to speed things up, but make sure that the users don't actually mind their transactions being rolled back, the best bet is to just turn off systems that are accessing the database before doing this maintenance so there are no connections open anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to change the path. But you have to manually move the files to the new location. The `WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE` speeds up the offline procedure by disconnecting any current connections.

```
ALTER DATABASE <db-name> SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
ALTER DATABASE <db-name> MODIFY FILE ( NAME = <db-name>, FILENAME = <db-path\filename.mdf> );
ALTER DATABASE <db-name> SET ONLINE;
```

For more info check the relevant [MSDN article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345483.aspx)